# Possible to increment token id automatically for mint function?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Currently I send always a new tokenId to the mint function. There is also a check if the tokenId already has been minted.

Would it be possible to automatically increment the tokenId? So I dont have to send a new one to the mint function everytime.

Here is my contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MintWithWhitelist is ERC1155, Ownable(msg.sender) {
    mapping(uint256 => string) private _tokenURIs;
    mapping(uint256 => bool) private _mintedTokens;

    constructor() ERC1155("") {}

    function name() public pure returns (string memory) {
        return "Collection name";
    }

    function symbol() public pure returns (string memory) {
        return "SYMBOL";
    }

    function uri(uint256 tokenId) public view override returns (string memory) {
        return _tokenURIs[tokenId];
    }

    function mint(
        address account,
        uint256 id,
        uint256 amount,
        string calldata tokenUri,
        bytes memory data
    ) public {
        require(whitelist[msg.sender], "Account is not in whitelist");
        require(!_mintedTokens[id], "Token ID has already been minted");
        _mintedTokens[id] = true;
        _mint(account, id, amount, data);
        _tokenURIs[id] = tokenUri;
    }

    mapping(address => bool) public whitelist;

    function addToWhitelist(
        address[] calldata toAddAddresses
    ) external onlyOwner {
        for (uint i = 0; i < toAddAddresses.length; i++) {
            whitelist[toAddAddresses[i]] = true;
        }
    }

    function removeFromWhitelist(
        address[] calldata toRemoveAddresses
    ) external onlyOwner {
        for (uint i = 0; i < toRemoveAddresses.length; i++) {
            delete whitelist[toRemoveAddresses[i]];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.

You can just store the next available ID in the contract state. In the mint function you'd assign that and increment the stored value. You probably wouldn't need `_mintedTokens`. Pseudocode:

```
uint256 public nextId;
function mint(...) {    
    ...
    _mint(account, nextId, amount, data);
    nextId++;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Lauri. It works perfectly!